# Nested Enumerate has indentation issues

Tags: enumerate, itemize, minipage

My itemize environment has customized bullet items. Since I aligned them vertically I have the problem, that my nested enumerate environment is not indented correctly.

The first enumerate item is off to the right, while the remaining items are placed to the left, so overall they are not alligned.

I want the nested enumerate items (1. 2. 3. ...) to be aligned with the text of the parent itemize environment. So, how do I solve this issue? Examples are listed below.

---

**What it looks like:**

```
      *  1984
      *  Adi Drotleff
      *  €24.594m
      *  CAD-Software
      ?    1. Fast grower
        2. Long time dividend payer
        3. Growing Dividend 20\%
```

**What I want:**

```
      *  1984
      *  Adi Drotleff
      *  €24.594m
      *  CAD-Software
      ?  1. Fast grower
         2. Long time dividend payer
         3. Growing Dividend 20\%
```

---

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{enumitem,varwidth}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\SetLabelAlign{center}{\clap{#1}} % For vertical alignment of custome bullets

\setlist{itemsep=-0.2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0,3\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[wide, labelsep = 1em, align=center]\scriptsize
        \item [\faAsterisk] 1984
        \item [\faMale] Adi Drotleff
        \item [\faEuro] \faEuro \num{24.594} m
        \item [\faIndustry] CAD-Software
        \item [\faQuestion]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Fast grower
            \item Long time dividend payer
            \item Growing Dividend 20\%
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: something like the answer below -- have a look

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{enumitem,varwidth}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome, siunitx}





\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[align=left, leftmargin=0pt, listparindent=\parindent, labelwidth=1cm, itemindent=!]\scriptsize
    \item [\faAsterisk] 1984
    \item [\faMale] Adi Drotleff
    \item [\faEuro]  \num{24.594} m
    \item [\faIndustry] CAD-Software
%   \item [\faQuestion]
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left, leftmargin=2cm]
        \item Fast grower
        \item Long time dividend payer
        \item Growing Dividend 20\%
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. There are two issues: 1. The custom bullet icons are not aligned anymore. 2. The Question-Mark is gone now. If I include it again, the alignment of the enumerate environment is gone

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that all it needed, was to get rid of the arguments for the parent itemize environment except for the `align=center` argument.
The customized bullets stay where they are supposed to be and the enumerate environment is correctly shown.

The only problem is, that the space between the bullets and the items text has now increased

```
\begin{minipage}{0,3\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[align=center]\scriptsize
        \item [\faAsterisk] 1984
        \item [\faMale] Adi Drotleff
        \item [\faEuro] \faEuro \num{24.594} m
        \item [\faIndustry] CAD-Software
        \item [\faQuestion]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Fast grower
            \item Long time dividend payer
            \item Growing Dividend 20\%
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```